# Floating DIVs and 100% height

Tags: css, css-float

I have try multiple solutions from StackOverflow but any of them is not working for my code which in a simple way looks like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Right side content, often short</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Left side sidebar, often twice much longer than right side content</div>
</div>
```

and CSS for it:

```
.container {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #00ffff;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.content {
   background: #666;
   width: 70%;
   float: right;
}
```

As I wrote above I have tested selected solutions which in most cases are for a right column bigger than left one but not opposite  way as I have above.

**UPDATE:** I have ended up adding `min-height` attribute to floating right column with a value which will fix smallest content appearance. Any solution wasn't working for that particular theme.

Comment: So you want left and right div to be same height?

Comment: Your style rule has an error "sideabr" ... shoud be sidebar

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/127/

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelled `.sidebar` as `.sideabr` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below styling, it would fix your problem:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #00ffff;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
   background: #666;
   width: 70%;
   float: right;
   height: 100%;
}
```